# Apache - MySQL Service detected with wrong path. / Ports already in use

Tags: mysql, apache, path, xampp, port

I'm getting the following errors when I launch XAMPP.

```
12:35:23  [main]    Initializing Control Panel
12:35:23  [main]    Windows Version:   64-bit
12:35:23  [main]    XAMPP Version: 1.8.1
12:35:23  [main]    Control Panel Version: 3.1.0 3.1.0 [ Compiled: September 20th 2012 ]
12:35:23  [main]    Running with Administrator rights - good!
12:35:23  [main]    XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp\"
12:35:23  [main]    Checking for prerequisites
12:35:23  [main]    All prerequisites found
12:35:23  [main]    Initializing Modules
12:35:23  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 80
12:35:23  [Apache]  XAMPP Apache Service is already running on port 443
12:35:23  [mysql]   MySQL Service detected with wrong path
12:35:23  [mysql]   Change XAMPP MySQL settings or
12:35:23  [mysql]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
12:35:23  [mysql]   Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL
12:35:23  [mysql]   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
12:35:23  [mysql]   Problem detected!
12:35:23  [mysql]   Port 3306 in use by "mysqld.exe"!
12:35:23  [mysql]   MySQL WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
12:35:23  [mysql]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
12:35:23  [mysql]   or reconfigure MySQL to listen on a different port
12:35:23  [main]    Starting Check-Timer
12:35:23  [main]    Control Panel Ready
```

I wasn't able to find a proper solution on google, so I'm kinda' hoping someone could help me out with this.

Oh and, XAMPP is running properly. Apache and the MySQL service are both running ..

Comment: You have already MySQL process running in your machine. Try to disable the service in `Services` (Win+R -> services.msc and search a MySQL service).

Comment: But what MySQL process am I cancelling if I do so? As I actually want to keep it running for the sake of Apache .. - Sorry, I'm kinda' new to this.

Comment: You have a process running in the port 3306, and probably is another mysql process. You can try to remove it, or change the port of the mysql process in XAMPP.

Answer (score 97):

1. Go to cmd and run it with Administrator mode.
2. Uninstall mysql service through command prompt using the following command.

   ```
           sc delete mysql
   ```
3. restart XAMPP

Comment: After this you may need to follow through with [Ton's procedure](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16981388/3376305)

Comment: It works like a charm. OP should mark this as accepted answer to help others to find the right solution.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Windows 10. I had already removed MySQL from the computer, but hadn't removed the service.

Comment: Worked on windows 10. Thanks

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem has been resolved.

Comment: Worked for me as well on Windows 11, crazy

Answer (score 25):

To delete existing service is not good solution for me, because on port 3306 run MySQL, which need other service. But it is possible to run two MySQL services at one time (one with other name and port). I found the solution here: http://emjaywebdesigns.com/xampp-and-multiple-instances-of-mysql-on-windows/

Here is my modified setting:
Edit your “my.ini” file in c:\xampp\mysql\bin\ 
  Change all default 3306 port entries to a new value 3308

edit your “php.ini” in c:\xampp\php and replace 3306 by 3308

Create the service entry - in Windows command line type

> sc.exe create "mysqlweb" binPath= "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
>   --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysqlweb"

Open Windows Services and set Startup Type: Automatic, Start the service

Comment: How do I change the defaults now for XAMPP Control Panel. It is still giving me the error: MyCQL WILL NOT Start without the configured ports free!
Port 3306 in use by ""C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini" MySQL57"!

Comment: nevermind I figured it out. On the XAMPP control panel go to config -> service and port settings -> mysql -> change 3306 to 3308 -> save save save!

Answer (score 13):

This is how I solved similar problem:

1. Launch XAMPP Control Panel.
2. Uninstall the MySQL service: click 'green check' button beside MySQL, under **Service** column. The 'green check' button will change into 'red cross' button.
3. Exit XAMPP, and relaunch it again.
4. Click Start.

I hope it can help solve your problem too.

Comment: Over 10 years later, still the answer that worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly enter `cmd`.

Then write:

```
sc delete MySQL
```

After that restart your computer. When restarting your computer and opening your `xampp`, you can see cross symbol on the `MySQL`. Click the cross symbol and click the start. That's all.

Comment: that answer is at the top

Answer (score 6):

Set XAMPP controlpanel to run under Administrator priviledges.

In Win 7
1. First make sure XAMPP control panel is not running
2. SHIFT+right click on XAMPP Control Panel 
3. Click on properties 
4. In properties select tab 'Compatibility'
5. On bottom of the tab under 'Privilege level' check the box "Run this program as an administrator"
6. Click OK

this worked for me

Comment: In my system I was getting the error messages too although Apache was installed as a service. When I unchecked the box then checked it again, the error messages went away. I may have done the install-as-a-service outside of XAMPP which caused a conflict.

Answer (score 4):

Ok so i found out the problem :)

ctrl+alt+delete to start task manager, once you get to task manager go to services. find MySQL and right click on it. Then click stop process. That worked for me and i hope it works for you :D

Answer (score 1):

about this *specific* issue:

```
12:35:23  [mysql]   Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini" MySQL
12:35:23  [mysql]   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
```

notice that **.exe** is missing from 1st row at the end of mysqld.

To fix this, start **regedit.exe** and change 
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\mysql` **ImagePath** 
by adding the **.exe** extension.

Restart *xampp control panel* and this error should not show up.

Comment: This is the hint that pointed me to a solution that worked for me. Check my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

its because you probaly installed wamp server and uninstall it but wampmysql.exe still running and using the default mysql port
go to msconfig
under services tab  uncheck wampmysqld to deactivate it
reboot the computer should work

Answer (score 0):

- Ok it's very easy actually to solve this...most of you who are presented with this problem probably don't even realize you don't have the full software yet installed :)
  I tried looking online with little success except some1 mentioned you need to look for those services running already. Forexample problem with filezilla you look in task manager for **filezilla** and you stop the process then you click the X in the xampp control pannel to install filezilla and then click run and it should start the service normally showing you a green lite with a check mark.
- Same goes for **mysql** issues.
- As for the **apache** problem, it usualy is a problem with the port being overtaken by skype or some other program, but you can find info how to solve that on the net easily :)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved mine, using [mircea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59424736/9336757) answer above.

From the error above, copy the mentioned Expected Path.

Start regedit.exe, go to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE then SYSTEM then CurrentControlSet then services then MySQL. Click ImagePath, Edit, Modify. Paste the Expected path copied from the above into the Value data field, Press OK, close regedit. Restart Xampp.

That is how it worked for me, for I'm having MSSQL server installed and running and didn't want to do away with it.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this issue caused because my local machine used to the one MySQL service installed earlier at 3006 port.
Thus I modified both **my.ini** (C:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini) and **php.ini** (C:\xampp\php\php.ini) files replaced port 3006 to 3008

After that I've created a new service running the command described above by **Tommer**:

sc.exe create "mysqlweb" binPath= "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysqlweb"

Answer (score -1):

hello i have had same problem an i did the steps with tommer and the problem solved thank you

**note** :

you don't have to go to that like just do this ;

1)--  Edit your “my.ini” file in c:\xampp\mysql\bin\ Change all default 3306 port entries to a new value 3308

2)--edit your “php.ini” in c:\xampp\php and replace 3306 by 3308

3)--Create the service entry - in Windows command line type

sc.exe create "mysqlweb" binPath= "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysqlweb"

4)--Open Windows Services and set Startup Type: Automatic, Start the service