# Unable to open PhpMyAdmin (Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

![PhpMyAdmin][1]

Xampp ControlPanel Log:

- 9:44:54 PM  [mysql]  MySQL Service detected with wrong path
- 9:44:54 PM  [mysql]  Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings
  or
- 9:44:54 PM  [mysql]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually
  first
- 9:44:54 PM  [mysql]  Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server
  5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults-file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
- 9:44:54 PM  [mysql]  Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
  --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

When I try to access http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ I am getting the below error.

- Cannot connect: invalid settings.
- Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
- phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server
  rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and
  password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to
  the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, I'd check in phpmyadmin configuration file and look for "auth_type" setting.

If it's set to "config" it means you also have to specify a "user" and "password" for the server. This configuration means phpMyAdmin will open without asking for password.

If it's set to "cookie" you will be asked for your MySQL user and password.

See [phpMyAdmin](https://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/Auth_types) docs for more details.

P.S. since you're using XAMPP, which I don't, you may have a different situation and my answer may not apply at all.

Comment: Yes Francesco it's little different in XAMPP. However, thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the below link I followed Hasan instructions. It resolved the problem

[Apache - MySQL Service detected with wrong path. / Ports already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718157/apache-mysql-service-detected-with-wrong-path-ports-already-in-use)

I even changed the password in config.inc.php

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I changed the password in /opt/lampp/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php on linux

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
on line 46 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = '';

i add controlpass as 'pma' save like below 
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser'] = 'pma';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass'] = 'pma';

done !