# Xampp - MySQL Service detected with wrong path. I have Windows 10

Tags: mysql, apache, path, server, xampp

I tried some similar questions but they didn't help me yet...

In xampp, I clicked Start on MySQL and it wrote to me:

> 'MySQL Service detected with wrong path Change XAMPP MySQL and Control
>   Panel settings or Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>   Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld"
>   --defaults-file="C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe
>   --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql'

When I clicked 'Start' again, it wrote:

'Attempting to start MySQL service...',
but nothing happened, just wrote this:

'There may be an error, return code: 1223 - The operation was canceled by the user.'

I'm new to this and really don't know what to do...

P.S: Apache works fine.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: where did you install xampp? Into program files?

Comment: XAMPP like most WAMP stacks prefer's to be installed at the root of a drive. Did you install in `C:\xampp` and then copy to `program files` ?

Comment: Or did you copy a `my.ini` from a xampp that was installed in `c:\xampp`

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718157/apache-mysql-service-detected-with-wrong-path-ports-already-in-use

Comment: @RiggsFolly when I click on MySQL service in xampp conrol panel, there is a pop up that says: "net command is requesting your permission mysql xampp" and it doesn't start...

Answer (score 0):

Here is my modified setting: Edit your “my.ini” file in c:\xampp\mysql\bin\ Change all default 3306 port entries to a new value 3308

edit your “php.ini” in c:\xampp\php and replace 3306 by 3308

Create the service entry - in Windows command line type

sc.exe create "mysqlweb" binPath= "C:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysqlweb"

Open Windows Services and set Startup Type: Automatic, Start the service