# Maintaining multiple installations of MySQL

Tags: mysql, xampp, mariadb

I have two installs of MySQL: one is a custom installation of MariaDB, and the other came prepackaged with XAMPP. Ideally I'd like to keep both and run either at separate times (I have no reason to run them together - thus port conflicting shouldn't be an issue).

When I run my MariaDB install, it runs fine. When I try running XAMPP install, it warns me "MySQL Service detected with wrong path," and doesn't get past "Attempting to start MySQL service..." when I try to run MySQL.

It also says "Found Path:" detecting the path to my MariaDB install, and "Expected Path:" indicating the location of the install prepackaged with XAMPP. What I don't understand is how it's even finding my MariaDB install.

I'm guessing it's something simple - any help is appreciated!

**Details:**
Windows 10
MariaDB 10.2.11
XAMPP v3.2.2

**EDIT:**
A similar question is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718157/apache-mysql-service-detected-with-wrong-path-ports-already-in-use). However, my issue is not that the ports are conflicting, since my MariaDB install is not running. Notwithstanding, I've tried the solutions provided there, and still to no avail.

Comment: The best way to do this is to have multiple VMs, each with their own DB instance. Like angry cats MySQL and MariaDB won't co-exist on the same system without carefully configuring them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache - MySQL Service detected with wrong path. / Ports already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718157/apache-mysql-service-detected-with-wrong-path-ports-already-in-use)

Comment: Use a portable version of XAMPP. Though from my experience it's not that simple.

Comment: Meh, VMs @tadman - Docker would be better I reckon. Although I suppose on Windows it makes little difference.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Docker or Vagrant are both simple solutions to this, and both are VM-based. Whatever works best!

Comment: @tadman my point was that Docker on UNIX is _not_ VM based - it's namespace/cgroup based. So it's lighter weight and usually far more performant. But either way - isolation of the multiple database instances is essential for happines.

Comment: @BoristheSpider This question is explicitly Windows 10, so cgroup implications are irrelevant. VM overhead is pretty marginal anyway, it's not worth stressing about, especially for development environments. One advantage of a full VM is the ability to snapshot and restore the database's state quickly and easily, something a lot more fussy if it's installed on the host OS.